# Reading and reconstructing symmetric matrix with R

Tags: r, file, dataframe, parsing, matrix

I need to read the following matrix from a file. It's a *symmetric*  correlation matrix, so half of it is omitted.

```
  1.00  
  0.49  1.00  
  0.53  0.57  1.00  
  0.49  0.46  0.48  1.00  
  0.51  0.53  0.57  0.57  1.00  
  0.33  0.30  0.31  0.24  0.38  1.00  
  0.32  0.21  0.23  0.22  0.32  0.43  1.00  
  0.20  0.16  0.14  0.12  0.17  0.27  0.33  1.00  
  0.19  0.08  0.07  0.19  0.23  0.24  0.26  0.25  1.00  
  0.30  0.27  0.24  0.21  0.32  0.34  0.54  0.46  0.28  1.00  
  0.37  0.35  0.37  0.29  0.36  0.37  0.32  0.29  0.30  0.35  1.00  
  0.21  0.20  0.18  0.16  0.27  0.40  0.58  0.45  0.27  0.59  0.31  1.00
```

Currently, I'm using

```
data1 <- na.omit(as.vector(t(read.table('triangle-data.txt', fill = TRUE))))
pt <- 12
R <- matrix(0, nrow = pt , ncol = pt)
for(i in 1:pt){
  R[i, 1:i] <- data1[(i*(i-1)/2 + 1): (i*(i+1)/2)]
}
R <- R + t(R) - diag(rep(1, pt))
R
```

The result is

```
> dput(R)
structure(c(1, 0.49, 0.53, 0.49, 0.51, 0.33, 0.32, 0.2, 0.19, 
0.3, 0.37, 0.21, 0.49, 1, 0.57, 0.46, 0.53, 0.3, 0.21, 0.16, 
0.08, 0.27, 0.35, 0.2, 0.53, 0.57, 1, 0.48, 0.57, 0.31, 0.23, 
0.14, 0.07, 0.24, 0.37, 0.18, 0.49, 0.46, 0.48, 1, 0.57, 0.24, 
0.22, 0.12, 0.19, 0.21, 0.29, 0.16, 0.51, 0.53, 0.57, 0.57, 1, 
0.38, 0.32, 0.17, 0.23, 0.32, 0.36, 0.27, 0.33, 0.3, 0.31, 0.24, 
0.38, 1, 0.43, 0.27, 0.24, 0.34, 0.37, 0.4, 0.32, 0.21, 0.23, 
0.22, 0.32, 0.43, 1, 0.33, 0.26, 0.54, 0.32, 0.58, 0.2, 0.16, 
0.14, 0.12, 0.17, 0.27, 0.33, 1, 0.25, 0.46, 0.29, 0.45, 0.19, 
0.08, 0.07, 0.19, 0.23, 0.24, 0.26, 0.25, 1, 0.28, 0.3, 0.27, 
0.3, 0.27, 0.24, 0.21, 0.32, 0.34, 0.54, 0.46, 0.28, 1, 0.35, 
0.59, 0.37, 0.35, 0.37, 0.29, 0.36, 0.37, 0.32, 0.29, 0.3, 0.35, 
1, 0.31, 0.21, 0.2, 0.18, 0.16, 0.27, 0.4, 0.58, 0.45, 0.27, 
0.59, 0.31, 1), .Dim = c(12L, 12L))
```

This is too unwieldy, and I need to hard-code its size. Is there a more convenient way?

Comment: @RonakShah That's true. The resulting matrix should be symmetric, with a lower triangle read from the file.

Comment: @RonakShah I don't think so. Please note that `data1` is a vector, rather than a matrix.

Comment: @RonakShah That gives me a weird result, `'data.frame': 21 obs. of  5 variables: ...`. I have no idea why R thinks the table has 5 columns instead of 12, but it just does.

Comment: `data1[upper.tri(data1)] <- data1[lower.tri(data1)]` will not produce a symmetric matrix.

Comment: To compute `pt`, you can use `Re(polyroot(c(-length(data1), 1/2, 1/2)))[1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a combination of `readLines` and `strsplit` to read the file

```
a <- sapply(sapply(lapply(readLines("triangle.txt"), 
                          function(x) strsplit(x, " ")), "[", 1), 
            function(x) na.omit(as.numeric(x)))
```

and `rbind` to cast it into a square matrix

```
A <- do.call("rbind", a)
```

Despite the warning, the lower part of the matrix is correctly read from the file, but the upper part is all messed up, which I fixed with a little dirty trick

```
A[upper.tri(A)] <- 0
A <- A + t(A) - diag(nrow(A))
```

---

EDIT

Another simpler solution based on the vector of the coefficients:

```
data1 <- na.omit(as.vector(t(read.table('triangle.txt', fill = TRUE))))
n <- Re(polyroot(c(-length(data1), 1/2, 1/2)))[1]
A <- matrix(0, n, n)
A[upper.tri(A, diag = T)] <- data1
A <- A + t(A) - diag(n)
```